# Changing element Id using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code on JsFidlle

http://jsfiddle.net/MzJaH/14/

I want to change the Id of the a elements with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.chapter a[href*="wikipedia"]').attr({
        rel: 'external',
        title: function () {
            return 'Learn more about ' + $(this).text() + ' at Wikipedia.';
        },
        id: function (index, oldValue) {
            return 'wikilink-' + index;
        }
    });
});
```

I wanted the anchor tags to be id='wikilink-0' but it doesnt happen....

And I dont know why I need this var oldValud there in function(index, oldValue) ...

Comment: "but it doesnt happen" --- it does

Comment: Exactly it works. id gets added...

Comment: Your code works as-is in the fiddle you provided.

Comment: As stated here - functions are eval'ed correctly - http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr

Comment: Try to read the source-code of the frame ...
I have no Id='wikilink-0'....

Comment: @Ze Carioca Silva: it changes it. How do you check it?

Comment: `<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon" rel="external" title="Learn more about Pentagons
 at Wikipedia." id="wikilink-0">Pentagons
</a>` - this is the exact copy-paste from jsfiddle

Comment: Well... I dont know what is happening... All I have is this:

<a
href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon">Pentagons
</a>.

And it happens in all browsers...

Comment: Don't look at the source code frame. jsFiddle doesn't update that! Right click the result pane and view that frame's source.

Comment: If you're expecting changes to the HTML to be visible in the "HTML" window in jsFiddle, then you're looking at the wrong place. Try instead, right-clicking the element and choosing "inspect element".

Comment: @Snixtor now I can see the changes... thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why I need this var oldValue there in function(index, oldValue) .

If you already have an id set for the element you will get it in the oldvalue.